# Create index on Coordinates elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have an embedded document in my mongodoctrine which is

```
<?php
namespace ng\MyBundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/** @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument */
class Coordinates
{
    /** @MongoDB\Float */
    protected $lat;

    /** @MongoDB\Float */
    protected $lng;

    public function __construct($lat = 0.0, $lng = 0.0)
    {
        $this->setLat($lat);
        $this->setLng($lng);
    }
    /**
     * Set lat
     *
     * @param float $lat
     * @return \Coordinates
     */
    public function setLat($lat)
    {
        $this->lat = $lat;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lat
     *
     * @return float $lat
     */
    public function getLat()
    {
        return $this->lat;
    }

    /**
     * Set lng
     *
     * @param float $lng
     * @return \Coordinates
     */
    public function setLng($lng)
    {
        $this->lng = $lng;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lng
     *
     * @return float $lng
     */
    public function getLng()
    {
        return $this->lng;
    }
}
```

and I want to have elastic search index on this embedded document which is a field called coordinates in my model.
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you already have your documents syncing from MongoDB to ElasticSearch? It sounds like the issue here is just working out how you add the geo index in ElasticSearch. [Spatial Search ElasticSearch tutorial](http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/spatial-search-tutorial.html) is probably a good starting point :)

Comment: Yes it's already syncing. 
My problem is that : Do I have to store all my collection fields into the elasticsearch index? 
I only need like 3 fields out of 10 ! :)